# Mapping Laravel Eloquent results to multidimensional array?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

So I have a db table with three columns: `client`, `project`, and `size`.

Each client is associated with many projects, and each project is associated with many sizes.  Using Eloquent, I'm trying to find the most efficient way to pull the data and put it into an array that looks like this:

```
    $array = [
        [
            'client1' => [
                'project' => 'Alpha',
                'sizes' => ['300', '400', '500']
            ]
        ],
        [
            'client2' => [
                'project' => 'Delta',
                'sizes' => ['200', '400', '600']
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

It seems I could just use nested foreach loops, moving from clients to projects to sizes, but there must be a better way in Laravel.  The documentation is a little sparse and I can't find an obvious way to do this.  What would be the best way?  Or am I even approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this correct, since you not include your eloquent query, or table structures.

After defining the model relationship,
I do it like this:

```
$data = Client::with(project.size)->get();
```

What it does is, eloquent will use Client table, and display all the client, and access the project and the project size for each client.

But this only work if you designed you database correctly, and defined the correct model relationship.

Assuming that you have 3 table, Client, Project and Size, and each table have the respective foreign keys.

Example for the model relationship:

Client model:

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}

public function size()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Size','App\Project');
}
```

Project model:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}

public function size()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Size');
}
```

Size model:

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

Comment: I see.  So I would need to put the columns in separate tables?  Right now they are all in the same table called 'jobs'.

Comment: Yes it should be like that. You should "normalize" your database. http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php